# how to wrap drupals taxonomy term node list a div

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, nodes, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-themes

i need to wrap the nodes teaser in a div for my taxonomy term page but cant figure out how.

[this is my page](http://bazarcha.ir/products) , this is a list of nodes for the `products` taxonomy term, using `node--product.tpl.php` i warped the individual node in `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>` but now i need to wrap the list of nodes in `<div class='row'></div>` and just for the `products` taxonomy term page listing ...

how can i do this ???

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Views, it lets you override how listings are displayed, and provide your own markup.

In drupal 7, taxonomy pages are views that you can override as well.